# Why am I getting a syntax error in Yacc when my grammar appears to cover all the input?

Tags: syntax, grammar, yacc, lex

I am currently trying to create a basic grammar that can take in and recognize shell commands. However, I am getting syntax errors that escape my understanding. I have drawn out a tree and, from what I can tell, I cover all the bases. Here is my lex file

```
%{

#include <cstring>
#include "y.tab.hh"

static  void yyunput (int c,char *buf_ptr  );

void myunputc(int c) {
  unput(c);
}

%}

%option noyywrap

%%

  return PIPE;
}

"<" {
  return LESS;
}

"&" {
  return AMP;
}

\n {
  return NEWLINE;
}

[ \t] {
  /* Discard spaces and tabs */
}

">" {
  return GREAT;
}

"2>" {
  return TGREAT;
}

">&" {
  return GREATAMP;
}

">>" {
  return DUBGREAT;
}

">>&" {
  return DUBGREATAMP;
}



[^ \t\n][^ \t\n]*  {
  /* Assume that file names have only alpha chars */
  yylval.cpp_string = new std::string(yytext);
  return WORD;
}
```

And here is my yacc file

```
%code requires 
{
#include <string>

#if __cplusplus > 199711L
#define register      // Deprecated in C++11 so remove the keyword
#endif
}

%union
{
  char        *string_val;
  // Example of using a c++ type in yacc
  std::string *cpp_string;
}

%token <cpp_string> WORD
%token NOTOKEN GREAT NEWLINE PIPE LESS AMP TGREAT GREATAMP DUBGREAT DUBGREATAMP

%{
//#define yylex yylex
#include <cstdio>
#include "shell.hh"

void yyerror(const char * s);
int yylex();

%}

%%

goal:
  command_list
  ;

command_list:
  command_line
  | command_list command_line
  ;

command_line:
  pipe_list io_modifier_list background_optional NEWLINE
  | NEWLINE
  | error NEWLINE{yyerrok;}
  ;

pipe_list:
  pipe_list PIPE command_and_args
  | command_and_args
  ;

command_and_args:
  command_word argument_list {
    Shell::_currentCommand.
    insertSimpleCommand( Command::_currentSimpleCommand );
  }
  ;

argument_list:
  argument_list argument
  | /* can be empty */
  ;


io_modifier_list:
  io_modifier_list iomodifier_opt
  | /*empty*/
  ;


iomodifier_opt:
  GREAT WORD {
    printf("   Yacc: insert output \"%s\"\n", $2->c_str());
    Shell::_currentCommand._outFile = $2;
  }
  | DUBGREAT WORD {
    printf("   Yacc: insert output \"%s\"\n", $2->c_str());
    Shell::_currentCommand._outFile = $2;
  }
  | DUBGREATAMP WORD {
    printf("   Yacc: insert output \"%s\"\n", $2->c_str());
    Shell::_currentCommand._outFile = $2;
    Shell::_currentCommand._background = true;
  }
  | GREATAMP WORD {
    printf("   Yacc: insert output \"%s\"\n", $2->c_str());
    Shell::_currentCommand._outFile = $2;
    Shell::_currentCommand._background = true;
  }
  | LESS WORD {
    printf("   Yacc: insert input \"%s\"\n", $2->c_str());
    Shell::_currentCommand._inFile = $2;
  }
  | /* can be empty */ 
  ;

background_optional:
  AMP {
    Shell::_currentCommand._background = true;
  }
  | /*empty*/
  ;

argument:
  WORD {
    printf("   Yacc: insert argument \"%s\"\n", $1->c_str());
    Command::_currentSimpleCommand->insertArgument( $1 );
  }
  ;

command_word:
  WORD {
    printf("   Yacc: insert command \"%s\"\n", $1->c_str());
    Command::_currentSimpleCommand = new SimpleCommand();
    Command::_currentSimpleCommand->insertArgument( $1 );
  }
  ;

%%

void
yyerror(const char * s)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"%s", s);
}

#if 0
main()
{
  yyparse();
}
#endif
```

In the simplest use case, I tried `ls -al`. In my understanding, ls gets recognized as a command_word. Then -al gets recognized as an argument. This creates a new argument_list containing only -al. From there, command_and_args is created from the command_word ls and the argument_list -al. This creates a pipe_list that only contains this command_and_args. From there, a command_line is created with this new pipe_list, an empty io_modifier_list, an empty background_optional, and the newline character when I hit enter. This creates a command_list, which is the goal. However, my understanding is apparently incorrect because I am getting a syntax error and I was hoping someone could help me fix that lack of understanding.

Comment: Something wrong with your lexer PIPE rule, for a start.

Comment: Doesn't bison produce conflict warnings?

Comment: @user207421 I somehow managed to delete that rule at some point, thanks. Now the syntax error is fixed; I get an infinite loop after entering anything. I put some print statements and something like 'ls' never reduces past command_word. Just a newline reduces to a command list but then infinite loops as well.

Comment: @rici it does but the internet wasn't helping me make sense of them. Turns out I managed to delete part of a rule as another commenter stated. Now there are no conflicts anymore but 'ls' never reduces past command_word and I don't know what could cause this.

Comment: I guess you need to edit your question then. I'm not sure what makes you think it is in an infinite loop; it seems more likely that it is waiting for more input. If you are asking about an issue with a grammar and bison reports parser conflicts, you should put that fact in the question. The fact that you don't know what causes them doesn't mean you can just ignore them; it could definitely help someone else understand your problem better.